# How to remove menu item from WordPress admin bar menu?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, litespeed

i want to remove an menu item from admin bar , tried the following code

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_items', 999 );
function remove_admin_menu_items() {

```
remove_menu_page('admin.php?page=litespeed&LSCWP_CTRL=purge&LSCWP_NONCE=ccd23d492e&litespeed_type=purge_all_lscache' );
```

}

unfortunately it doesn't work ! I have attached a screenshot of menu I want to remove
[image: want to remove litespeed Cache Plugin menu icon]

I like to hide the menu using the child theme function.php code.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin author posts the following:

> The best way to hide our menu is by CSS. For top icon in adminbar, use
> `.litespeed-top-toolbar {display:none}`. It can be done by using 3rd party plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-admin-css/ or

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_litespeed_icon');
function hide_litespeed_icon() {
    echo '<style>.litespeed-top-toolbar {display:none}</style>';
}
```

> into your theme’s functions.php

Alternatively, try adding the following code to `functions.php`:

```
function remove_lscwp_admin_menu($wp_admin_bar) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('litespeed-menu');
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'remove_lscwp_admin_menu', 999);
```